# UIScrollView appear not at the top, but random: at bottom, at the middle

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

i have a problem with my UIScrollView, i have created it in interface builder and then i have connected it to my view, but i have a bizarre problem, when i click to open the view with the scroll view, some time appear at the top, some time appear scrolled at the bottom, and some time in the middle for example, i want that appear always at the top, how i can do?...if i click on the status bar the uiscrollview scroll up how it should be, and i have also tried to add this:

```
[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

in my configure view in view will appear, but don't work appear scrolled random in every position...there is a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scrollRectToVisible to always have it appear in the same spot. Let's say you have a UIScrollView where the frame size is (100,100). And you have a content size of (100,200). If you wanted that to appear at the top, you would call:

```
[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) animated:NO];
```

if you wanted to center the content you would do this:

```
[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 100) animated:NO];
```

if this is not working for you, then your scrollview is not setup properly and you'd need to provide more details on how you set it up.

Comment: my scroll view frame is (320,235) and the content size change dynamic with the text view in their content, so how i can do?

Comment: if your content size is < scroll view frame, then it won't scroll at all so you don't have to worry about it. if your content size is > scroll view frame, then just do [self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,320,235) animated:NO].

Comment: What do you have inside your UIScrollView? You can position the items inside your scroll view using setFrame to layout whatever is in there before you use scrollRectToVisible.

Comment: my content size change dynamically because i have some UITextview that change height dynamically with the text i insert first the view will appear, so i have do this, i have add the element in interface builder, with not place them in the right position, there are only in the UIScrollView, then i have connected also this element with IBOOutletConnection to my view, and pragmatically i have positioned the right potision for every element, i have tried the line you write above but don't work...

Comment: Post a screenshot with your question. I don't understand what you are describing. UITextView inherits from UIScrollView so if you just need scrolling text, you don't need both. You just need a UITextView.